# How does Stack Overflow thrive on computer community?

Tags: discussion

I am going to open a Knowledge Community Service concerning about Contest in Korea, And I think Stack Overflow is a good example to succeed in hard circumstances.  So I have been developing a knowledge service in Korean for making many first starters to specialists about programming. I guess Stack Overflow is a late starter around many original knowledge services. But It took the first place in Java, Objective-C and many other mobile language communities. So I am very eager to know how you did it.

I wonder I can ask you few questions below.

1. How could you make this enormous specialist interest in here.?
2. Which is more important for success, looking for specialist in advance or secure general user?
3. What things were useful for advertising your site?
4. Did you have a lot of information about knowledge when you first started? How did you gather the information?
5. How many years does it take to settle down like this?
6. How much does the H/W Infra cost for managing the current size of your company?

Comment: For number 5, SO started in 2008, or at least that is the date of the oldest post I have seen.

Comment: `And I think Stackoverflow is a good example to succeed in hard circumstances.` Häh?

Comment: @UristMcBobby: The internet... It's a sea of hard circumstances :)

Comment: @David: “The internet is 95 percent porn and spam” ― Margaret Atwood ... now *that* makes your comment very interesting. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139380/179635

Answer (score 7):

Much of the information  you are looking for - about the sites' history, development, decisions and rationales, and philosophy - can be found online, if you are willing to put in the time to research:

- [On the Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) - especially in the [archive](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/archive/)
- In [Jeff Atwood's personal blog](http://codinghorror.com) - [Example 1](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html), [Example 2](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html)
- Here on Meta